# MVVM WPF - Usage of Viewmodels

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am having a WPF dataentry form which has got 3 comboboxes which needs to be filled with Master Details like Department, Job Title and Pay Type & other information. All these 3 master information needs to be fetched from the database. I am using LINQ to SQL as my data layer. I have already built the maintenance pages for these master information(i.e. 3 Viewmodels).

Now My Question:

Is it advisable to use these 3 view models for the comboboxes (which defeats the MVVM since there is more than one view model being used for a view) and directly bind them or is it ok if I just use 3 observablecollection of prime classes (Department, JobTitle & PayType).

I would really appreciate any help in this regard. I have lots of form with the same scenario and I am not able to decide on which route to take.

Thanks in advance.

Raja

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is fine to use three `ObservableCollection`s in your ViewModel class. This way you can use it as the `DataContext` of the view itself, which will make setting up the bindings much easier.

Comment: Thanks Andy. I was also of the same impression. You just made my decision simple :-)

Answer (score 0):

As a slight variation on this I might have used ObservableCollections of ViewModels.

This might not might not make sense in your case, but I've been finding it helpful in cases where the combo/list uses a fairly complex datatemplate and the user can interact with elements in the listitem...